# Spin 1/2 Fermion With Both Majorana and Dirac Masses?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, majorana-fermions

I will use Van der Waerden notation in the following:

It is easy to construct both Majorana and Dirac mass terms in the lagrangian of a Dirac spinor with left-handed component $\phi_{\alpha}$ and right handed component $\chi^{\dot\alpha}$, here they are:
$$L_{mass}=m_1(\phi^{\alpha}\phi_{\alpha}+\phi^*_{\dot\alpha}\phi^{*\dot\alpha})+m_2(\chi_{\dot\alpha}\chi^{\dot\alpha}+\chi^{*\alpha}\chi^*_{\alpha})+m_3(\chi^{*\alpha}\phi_{\alpha}+\phi^*_{\dot\alpha}\chi^{\dot\alpha})$$

$m_1$ and $m_2$ are Majorana masses for $\phi_{\alpha}$ and $\chi^{\dot\alpha}$ respectively, and $m_3$ is a Dirac mass.

I have never seen this ever considered however, is there a reason for this? Is it not possible to solve the equations of motion?

Comment: This is actually a commonly considered possibility. Perhaps the most common place this is discussed in the seesaw mechanism where right handed neutrinos have both Majorana and Dirac mass contributions.

Comment: Oh okay, good to know! Can the spectrum of this be solved exactly?

Comment: For a 2 Weyl fermion case, yes. Its just a 2 by 2 matrix which you can diagonalize exactly. For multiple generations it can become more challenging.